# How to define relationships between content items in Orchard CMS without select N+1

Tags: orchardcms

We currently have some parent child relationships between Orchard content items built using the Container/Containable structure.

The parent item is a manufacturer, the child item is a range, the child of a range is a product. We have this kind of parent child relationship 4 levels deep.

This is all working but on a page where we have a list of products from different manufacturers and want to display some information about the manufacturer with each product performance is terrible due to select n+1 issues.

This is because we are bringing in all the products in a single query, but then for each product a query is executed for the common part to find the container ID and then a separate query is executed for each manufacturer content item.

I've added query hints to get the common part eagerly, but we still have the select n+1 issue to get the actual parent content item, obviously at lower levels in the hierarchy this problem is magnified.

I think this is because of the lazy field for the Container on the CommonPart - I can't see a way of avoiding this with that structure, or telling the content manager to fetch it eagerly.

I then looked at defining the structure ourselves using http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-1-n-and-n-n-relations#BuildingaRelationBetweenContentItems but the example there for relationships between content types again uses lazy fields to load in the parent.

What I want is to execute a single query to get me every product with its parent range and its parent manufacturer, but I can't see how to do this. Are there any examples of this?

Comment: Hql might be the easiest way to get what you want.

Comment: I followed https://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/getting-orchard-content-items-out-of-hql and this is a good way of getting the ids of the content items I want, but I can't see how to populate my content items directly.

Comment: Once you have the ids, do a GetMany on ContentManager.